# Replace Helvetica Neue with a different font in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, css, mozilla

Is there a way to replace the font 'Helvetica Neue' with 'Verdana' in firefox via the userchrome.css, usercontent.css, or user.js? I find this font extremely hard to read without zooming the content. Thanks.

Comment: should probably be on superuser

Answer (score 0):

would -moz-font-family not work? I've never tried myself but you could give it a shot.

Comment: Well I don't know? I can't find any documentation for -moz-font-family. What extra features does -moz-font-family have from font-family?